# ASP.NET Membership provider unable to return user roles in LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to get a list of all the user with their roles using LINQ.
The application is based on Membership Provider ver.1, I suppose as i can see from the below config lines:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="2" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

My LINQ query is like this:

```
var users = (from u in db.Users
            join m in db.Memberships on u.UserId equals m.UserId
            select new 
            {
               m.Email,
               u.UserName,
               u.UserId,
               m.IsLockedOut,
               Roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName) //doesn't work   
             }).ToList();
```

The problem is that Roles = **Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName)** doesn't work as class **Roles hasn't any method GetRolesForUser()**

[image: Roles available methods]

I can't even make my query using UsersInRoles as this table is not mapped like you can see below.
[image: Entity Data Model]

Comment: Looks wrong,users:roles is m:m so how/why are they related directly?

Comment: First, you have a scope conflict. Noter that your local property has the same name as the static class. You could prefix the namespace. But ...

Comment: Second, you will find out that you can't call this in an EF query.

Comment: @HenkHolterman so you're telling me there is no way to get them? (in an elegant way I mean)

Comment: Well you are now mixing two access methods. Either use EF and see what type u.Roles is (EF handles the M:M) _or_ use GetAllUsers() and work from there.

Comment: @HenkHolterman You're right. Obviously UserRoles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName) can't work in EF ("LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method...". So the only way I see to make a query like this, is to create a VIEW in the DB joining users and roles and then managing the results to get a list of ["User","Roles"] as I want to avoid to make a query for each user row as each page will have at least 100 results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen that before very much, as I know when you want to get data using `LINQ` and use another `LINQ`, it dose not work.

the best way for this issue, is that you have to get all `Roles` before this `Query`(When your data saved in memory, you can get those data as easy) or make that method to `Awaitable` like this:

**With Memory**:

```
var allRoles = _roleMaganer.GetAllRoles();

var users = (from u in db.Users
        join m in db.Memberships on u.UserId equals m.UserId
        select new 
        {
           m.Email,
           u.UserName,
           u.UserId,
           m.IsLockedOut,
           Roles = allRoles.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.UserName == u.UserName)    
         }).ToList();
```

**With Awaitable**:

```
var users = (from u in db.Users
        join m in db.Memberships on u.UserId equals m.UserId
        select new 
        {
           m.Email,
           u.UserName,
           u.UserId,
           m.IsLockedOut,
           Roles = await Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName)   
         }).ToList();
```

> When the `GetRolesForUser` was `Async` or `MultyTask` when your base `Query` want to execute, and you don't used of `await` key, exception occured, because the EF can't make other a connection in one `Query`